# Mysql update all rows based on select from another table

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tabels;

```
mysql> describe ipinfo.ip_group_country;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ip_start     | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ip_cidr      | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| country_code | varchar(2)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| country_name | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe logs.logs;
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| ts                   | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| REMOTE_ADDR          | tinytext   | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| COUNTRY_CODE         | char(2)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I can select country code using ip address from first table:

```
mysql> SELECT country_code FROM ipinfo.`ip_group_country` where `ip_start` <= INET_ATON('74.125.45.100') order by ip_start desc limit 1;
+--------------+
| country_code |
+--------------+
| US           |
+--------------+
```

In logs.logs, I have all the REMOTE_ADDR (ip address) set, but all COUNTRY_CODE entries are empty. Now, I want to populate COUNTRY_CODE appropriately using the ipinfo table. How can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE logs.logs
SET COUNTRY_CODE = (
    SELECT country_code
    FROM ipinfo.ip_group_country
    WHERE ipinfo.ip_start <= INET_ATON(logs.REMOTE_ADDR)
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE COUNTRY_CODE IS NULL
```

If it fails saying the column types must match, you'll have to alter your logs.logs table so that the REMOTE_ADDR column is the same type (varchar(20)) as the ip_cidr table.

Answer (score 8):

In a single-table update you use `update t1 set c1=x where y`.

In a multi-table update you use `update t1, t2 set t1.c1=t2.c2 where t1.c3=t2.c4`

Here's the relevant documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

What you're looking for is something along the lines of (editted) `update logs.logs as l, ipinfo.ip_group_country as c set l.COUNTRY_CODE=c.country_code where c.ip_start <= INET_ATON(l.REMOTE_ADDR) order by c.ip_start asc`

Edit: you're right, the max() in the original answer I provided could not work. The query above should, although it will likely be less efficient than something like the approach in the answer provided below.

Comment: thank you. I get an error:  `mysql> update logs.logs as l, ipinfo.ip_group_country as c set l.COUNTRY_CODE=max(c.country_code) where c.ip_start <= INET_ATON(l.REMOTE_ADDR);
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right, I've editted it with something that should work better.